# Easy question: How to see design view in VS 2010 when editing an ASP.NET MVC 2 partial view? (ascx)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am editing and have already saved a Vendor.ascx partial view in VS 2010.  Since the html snippet would be very simple, I thought I would look at it in Design View, however the tab is no where to be seen.  I haven't seen any options in the menus either.  Any idea how to turn on Design view when editing an MVC .ascx partial view?

Comment: I believe that is intentional... how would it render the view at design time without model data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the Design View is off by default.  You need to go to Options, check "Show all settings", scroll down to "HTML Designer", select "Enable HTML designer (requires restart of Visual Studio)", restart, and bingo, three tabs at the bottom "Design", "Split", and "Source".  It actually renders the ascx file pretty well.